# Creating share buttons in iOS app ( twitter facebook...)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, twitter

I was wondering what is a good way to create share buttons in iOS, and by share buttons I mean these 3 kinds of buttons: 
1- Follow me on Twitter
2- Like a page on Facebook
3- Send a mail (Optional)
I have heard about sharekit but I am interested in just creating these 3 buttons that will be found on the back of the page of the app.

Comment: Basically, I just want to have a follow button to my twitter account and a like button for my facebook page. Both facebook and twitter offer these using HTML code, so I was wondering if there was a way to get these buttons for iOS apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting data to social services is much more complicated than just setting up a button. You must register your application, choose user, authenticate, then communicate via the internet.

ShareKit does most of that for you.

You may not just 'create share button' and have it share data to fb or twitter.

Comment: What about just a simple follow button and like button? It doesn't need sharing... Both twitter and Facebook offer Html codes in order to do that so I was wondering if there was the same for iOS apps

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
NSString *launchUrl = @"http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=USER NAME";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
```

which will open Mobile Safari and let you follow that user. You may be required to log in.
I guess there is a similar URL for Facebook.

To send a mail from within your app, use the [MessageUI Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Posting to those service is complicated because you'll have to create Apps on those social networks as well as handle the oauth handshake the occurs which allows your app to share on behalf of the user.  The Socialize SDK (www.getsocialize.com) is the fastest way to get Facebook/Twitter authentication without coding it yourself.  Sample code below:

```
Socialize* socialize = [[Socialize alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[self.socialize createShareForEntityWithKey:@"http://www.url.com" medium:SocializeShareMediumFacebook text:@"Check this out!"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ShareKit 2.0 
https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

I believe it supports sharing on most common social networks.